# create a multiple triggers for one table

Tags: java, mysql

I want to make a 2-3 triggers for 1 table. For example (these are my queries):

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER IF EXISTS insert_before_update_slugrapat BEFORE UPDATE ON slugrapat
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
INSERT INTO record_pemakaian_slug_rapat(rc_sr_size, rc_sr_stockawal, rc_sr_holling, rc_sr_store, rc_sr_sales, rc_sr_sisa, rc_sr_lastdate)
VALUES(new.sr_size, new.sr_stockawal, new.sr_holling, new.sr_store, new.sr_sales, new.sr_sisa, new.sr_lastdate); 
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER IF EXISTS insert_before_update_slugrapat BEFORE UPDATE ON slugrapat
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO so_slugrapat(sr_size, sr_sisa, sr_stockakhir, sr_stockopname, sr_lastdate)
VALUES(new.sr_size, new.sr_sisa, new.sr_stockakhir, new.sr_stockopname, new.sr_lastdate);
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

and the error says :

```
Error code 1064, SQL state 42000: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TRIGGER IF EXISTS insert_before_update_slugrapat BEFORE UPDATE ON slugrapat
FOR ' at line 1
```

I tried many ways that have been posted on stackoverflow but still it doesn't work.

Comment: Why is a stub `/` there?

Comment: why don't you combine all in to one, since they occur on same table `BEFORE UPDATE`?

Comment: err.. because i read in another post and it says for 2 triggers on the same script i must add "/" to replace "GO" in mysql. Is it wrong?

Comment: using the same trigger name `insert_before_update_slugrapat` twice with `REPLACE` clause?

Comment: i tried to combine all in to one, and the error says : Error code 1064, SQL state 42000: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TRIGGER IF EXISTS insert_before_update_slugrapat BEFORE UPDATE ON slugrapat
FOR ' at line 1

Comment: @SparKotॐ im totally confused.. firstly, i dont use the same trigger name but it also doesnt work..

Comment: I don't see `REPLACE` clause with `CREATE TRIGGER` in MySQL manual.

Comment: You changed the delimiter to `$$` but you are using `/` instead.

Comment: i already found the answer from sparkot.. thanks for your helps guysss !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this instead:

```
DROP TRIGGER insert_before_update_slugrapat;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER insert_before_update_slugrapat
   BEFORE UPDATE
   ON slugrapat
   FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO record_pemakaian_slug_rapat(rc_sr_size,
                                           rc_sr_stockawal,
                                           rc_sr_holling,
                                           rc_sr_store,
                                           rc_sr_sales,
                                           rc_sr_sisa,
                                           rc_sr_lastdate)
   VALUES (new.sr_size,
           new.sr_stockawal,
           new.sr_holling,
           new.sr_store,
           new.sr_sales,
           new.sr_sisa,
           new.sr_lastdate);

   INSERT INTO so_slugrapat(sr_size,
                            sr_sisa,
                            sr_stockakhir,
                            sr_stockopname,
                            sr_lastdate)
   VALUES (new.sr_size,
           new.sr_sisa,
           new.sr_stockakhir,
           new.sr_stockopname,
           new.sr_lastdate);
END$$
DELIMITER;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out two solutions.
1.Put all your code inside one trigger and use multiple begin and end statement
2.Remove delimiters, Begin and End

Comment: still doesnt work.. im confused because the error says : Error code 1064, SQL state 42000: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'insert_before_update_slugrapat BEFORE UPDATE ON slugrapat
FOR EACH ROW 
INSERT I' at line 1

Comment: First drop your existing trigger.
And in Mysql you cant replace trigger if exists and if it does it is loosing the definition of Trigger itself..

Comment: i already found the answer from sparkot.. thanks for your helps divy !

Answer (score 0):

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS insert_before_update_slugrapat;

CREATE  TRIGGER   insert_before_update_slugrapat BEFORE UPDATE ON slugrapat
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
INSERT INTO record_pemakaian_slug_rapat(rc_sr_size, rc_sr_stockawal, rc_sr_holling, rc_sr_store, rc_sr_sales, rc_sr_sisa, rc_sr_lastdate)
VALUES(new.sr_size, new.sr_stockawal, new.sr_holling, new.sr_store, new.sr_sales, new.sr_sisa, new.sr_lastdate); 
END $$

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS insert_before_update_slugrapat_1;
CREATE TRIGGER  insert_before_update_slugrapat_1 BEFORE UPDATE ON slugrapat
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO so_slugrapat(sr_size, sr_sisa, sr_stockakhir, sr_stockopname, sr_lastdate)
VALUES(new.sr_size, new.sr_sisa, new.sr_stockakhir, new.sr_stockopname, new.sr_lastdate);
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: i already found the answer from sparkot.. thanks for your helps Fathah !